# Excel - count number of rows that has a value in at least one of multiple columns

Tags: excel

I'm doing a survey of companies and have to collect and structure the data in excel.

I want to count the number of companies that have participated.

In the first column there are company names. In the other columns (4 of them) are the answers to the survey.

To find out how many companies have participated, I have to check to see in how many of the rows there is at least one value that is greater than 0 in either of the columns. So, if one of the values in any of the columns is greater than 0 for a given row, that represents a company that has participated. Therefore, I have to find out how many rows have at least one column where the value is greater than 0.

Comment: Add an item summing the four question cells on the same line in column F. Copy and paste for the length of the document. Autofilter on column F not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid having a helper column you could use `SUMPRODUCT` like this

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A100+B2:B100+C2:C100+D2:D100>0)+0)`

where A2:A100, B2:B100 etc. represent your 4 columns, adjust ranges as required

Answer (score 0):

You can add an helper (extra) column with some formula as =SUMIF(range,">0") and then in the end sum/count values greater than 0.